# Falhas de acesso ao pt.traducir.win

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Encontrei dois problemas ao utilizar o pt.traducir.win

#### Google Chrome (71.0.3578.98 64 bits):

Acessando: https://pt.traducir.win/notifications, recebo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.19180):

Acessando: https://pt.traducir.win, não carrega a página, e vejo o erro no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: oh, I think I know where I broke it... and I wasn't able to see that because I have a cached version of the file. I'll answer here once it's fixed (BTW, IE11 is not supported)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obrigado pelo seu relatório! (e fique à vontade para corrigir esta tradução automática)

Na semana passada eu joguei um pouco com como melhorar a velocidade do site (eu acabei usando `static.traducir.win` para os arquivos estáticos, que é extremamente rápido quando cacheado pelo cloudflare).

Entretanto, eu não o fiz de modo que `/lib/service-worker.js` (o trabalhador de serviço que é instalado para segurar as notificações) seja servido do usuário principal. Eu corrigi isso (e mais tarde eu estou indo para ver se eu posso tê-lo armazenado em cache também).

Isso deve estar funcionando agora. Deixe-me saber se ele não.

PS: IE11 não é realmente suportado, e eu não ficaria surpreso se o site quebrou de formas divertidas (em particular, eu não acho que IE11 manipula notificações push web, mas eu posso estar errado).

---

Thanks for your report!

Last week I played a bit with how to improve the site's speed (I ended up using `static.traducir.win` for the static files, which is extremely fast when cached by cloudflare).

However, I didn't make it so that `/lib/service-worker.js` (the service worker that's installed to handle the notifications) is served from the main server. I fixed that (and later I'm going to see if I can have it cached as well).

This should be working now. Let me know if it doesn't.

PS: IE11 isn't really supported, and I wouldn't be surprised if the site broke in fun ways (in particular, I don't think IE11 handles web push notifications, but I may be wrong).

Comment: it's working now.